# How to visualize a sequence of data from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, visualize

i have following input:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,  "A"],[2, "A"],[3, "B"],[4, "C"],[5, "D" ],[6, "A" ],[7, "B" ],[8, "A"], 
                           [9, "C" ],[10, "D" ],[11,"A" ],
                           [12,  "A"],[13, "B"],[14, "B"],[15, "D" ],[16, "A" ],[17, "B" ],[18, "A" ], 
                           [19, "C" ],[20, "D" ],[21,"A" ],
                           [22,  "A"],[23, "A"],[24, "C"],[25, "D" ],[26, "A" ],[27, "C" ],[28, "A" ], 
                           [29, "C" ],[30, "D" ],[31,"A" ]]),
                            columns=['No.',  'Value'])
```

This is the output:

```
    No. Value
0   1   A
1   2   A
2   3   B
3   4   C
4   5   D
5   6   A
6   7   B
7   8   A
8   9   C
9   10  D
10  11  A
11  12  A
12  13  B
13  14  B
14  15  D
15  16  A
16  17  B
17  18  A
18  19  C
19  20  D
20  21  A
21  22  A
22  23  A
23  24  C
24  25  D
25  26  A
26  27  C
27  28  A
28  29  C
29  30  D
30  31  A
```

Now i want to visualize all sequences that are in the data.

The first sequence should start with the first value in the data frame and ends with upcoming value of "D". So for example the first sequence is from No. 1 to No.5 (including).

The second sequence is from No.6 till the next Value of "D", No.10. And so on.

The Dataframe has six sequences in it.

How to visualize the sequences?

Comment: `Now i want to visualize all sequences that are in the data.` Can you explain more?

Comment: A possible Chart may have six sequences on the x-axis and fixed value like 1 on the y-axis. In each sequence e.g. sequence 1 the following values A-A-B-C-D could have an own colour for each bar.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
g = df['Value'].eq('D').shift().cumsum().bfill().astype(int)
df1 = df.groupby(g)['Value'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df1)
Value  A  B  C  D
Value            
0      2  1  1  1
1      2  1  1  1
2      2  2  0  1
3      2  1  1  1
4      3  0  1  1
5      2  0  2  1
6      1  0  0  0

df1.plot.bar()
```

Or:

```
g = df['Value'].eq('D').shift().cumsum().bfill().astype(int)
idx = df.groupby(g)['Value'].agg(''.join)
df1 = df.groupby(g)['Value'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0).set_index(idx)
print (df1)
Value  A  B  C  D
Value            
AABCD  2  1  1  1
ABACD  2  1  1  1
AABBD  2  2  0  1
ABACD  2  1  1  1
AAACD  3  0  1  1
ACACD  2  0  2  1
A      1  0  0  0

df1.plot.bar()
```

Comment: This looks nice, but i want something that can visualizie the sequence.

It my could look like "Serial Programming" https://forums.fast.ai/uploads/default/original/2X/4/4ebf88f00742be9b31e450097131c6bbb40fb7d1.png

Instead of seconds on the x-axis there should be "Sequence". The ticks should be be 0, then 1 for the first tick and so on.

And instead of the y-axis tasks there should be Value like A for the first tick, B for the second tick and so on.

Comment: @New16122019 - hmmm, not understand. And instead of tasks there should be Value - what is value here? Counts? or `1,2,3,4,5,6,7` ?

Comment: The values should be "A", "B", "C", and "D".

Comment: @ML-ME - Unfortunately not understand.

Comment: @ML-ME - Is possible create graph in excel from data in question?

Comment: I want to see if there is a pattern of the appearing sequences. Therefore i need a suitable visualization.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205923/discussion-between-jezrael-and-ml-me).

Answer (score 1):

Visualization of the sequence can be thought of as (number of sequences existing and their interval). If the above holds true.

You can try as :

replace D values as 'nan' in new column named seq

```
df.loc[df['Value'] != 'D', 'seq'] = 1
```

Then plot the df to visualize the sequences as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot('seq','ro',data=df)
```

The output will be as:

[image]

if D also needed to show. We can try below code:

```
df.loc[df['Value'] != 'D', 'seq'] = 1
df.loc[df['Value'] == 'D', 'seq'] = 2
```

Then plot the df to visualize the sequences as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot('seq','rd',data=df,linestyle='dashdot')
plt.plot('seq','gd',data=df,linestyle='dashed')
```

[image]

Comment: but what is if i want to visualize the D values too?

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check.